# Controlling Both Show's Plotting Order and Options Generally

Tags: plotting, graphics

Similar to [Changing the plotting order in Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210652/changing-the-plotting-order-in-show), I'd like to have control over plotting order with more advanced graphics, like a `Legended` `ListPlot` with `FrameLabels`. Specifics aside, I've adapted the solution from the previous question for my particular case:

```mathematica
Show[b, a, AbsoluteOptions[a]]
```

which works perfectly for me, up to the text used to label the plot and axes, which prints `FrameBox["Label", TraditionalForm ]` as if wrapped in one too many `FrameBox`es. Placing labeling within the `Show` also doesn't work.

#### My Best Answer So Far

It seems to me the most side-effect free way of `Show`ing things is to do the following:

1. Define desired settings in first plot (`a`)
2. Define other plots (`b..`)
3. Try `Show[..b, a, AbsoluteOptions[a]]`
4. For side-effected options, duplicate them *before* `AbsoluteOptions`. As placing options in `Show` do not perform the same lower-level routines (i.e. defining lower-level options) that functions like `Plot` and `ListPlot` do, this trick allows you to set a specific option you want (like the `FrameLabel` text), using `AbsoluteOptions` as the shim to add in all the lower-level details (like plot boundaries, text positions, spacing, etc.).

This worked in my case, but still leaves me with some open questions:

1. Where is `Options` better than `AbsoluteOptions` and vice versa?
2. What happens if your desired option is different enough from what's specified in `a` (using nomenclature from above) that some of the lower-level options are incorrect? E.g. say I specified a `FrameLabel` that was super long in `Show`, but not when defining `a`. (this is a case I could easily test, I will do so and revise this, but I also bet that this is generally a case for potential for side-effects)

---

#### Example

[Here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/031d0201-ef13-456a-9486-e077fededb59) is a faithful but reasonably minimal working example.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Please put the code into the question to ensure that is is preserved for the future

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the following seems to work:

```
GraphicsOptions[Legended[expr_, ___], rest___] := 
  GraphicsOptions[expr, rest]
GraphicsOptions[g_Graphics, rest___] := Options[g, rest]

Show[b, a$with$explicit$labels, GraphicsOptions[a$with$explicit$labels]]
```

[image]

This relies on the helper function `GraphicsOptions` to extract the "non-absolute" options from the potentially wrapped `Graphics` expression, which are then passed to `Show`.